# Guidance on main and master branch in github

Tags: git, github

I had created a remote repository in Github and pushed my project into that remote repository. After pushing it, a new branch is created `master` and now I have two branches `main` and `master`. The default branch is `main` which shouldn't be. At the time of the creation of the remote repository, I have added a `Readme.md` file maybe because of that `main` branch is created in the first place. Could you correct me here?

As of now, I have two branches, and I [changed the default branch to `master`](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch). For the `main` branch, it is showing as `main had recent pushes 43 minutes ago` and `compare & pull request` button. When I clicked the button it is showing as below.

***When the `main` branch is created, Is it because of adding Readme.md file? How can I do a pull request as I am developing a small project alone? Need some guidance on that.***
[image]

Comment: Make `master` the default branch and delete `main`.

Comment: I mentioned already that I changed the default branch to master. I want to do some hands-on like creating a new branch and then merging that branch to master branch. how can I do that?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid. could you provide me some tips like is it okay to merge one different branch to master branch without pulling requests? there is a lot to read I know could you help me with this particular concern.

Comment: You don't need to do pull requests if you're the only one working on the repository.

Comment: If a personal project's small enough and your work is linear, committing straight to master can be a valid option

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recently, GitHub has decided to [change the default branch](https://github.com/github/renaming) upon creating a new repo to `main`.

If you don't have any commits in `main` and you don`t need it, just delete that branch.

The screenshot you posted shows that there isn't anything to compare between the two branches and since you already made `master` the default, instead of `main`, you then don't really need `main`.

If you need to delete `main` there are many ways, either through the GitHub UI or command line ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)).

**Edit**

GitHub now provides a setting that allows you to change the name of the default branch to every repository through https://github.com/settings/repositories. Here you can revert back to "master" as your default branch name.

Comment: Is it okay to merge one different branch to the master branch without pulling requests? I want to do some hands-on on that. Can you provide me some useful links for that?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik you can merge a branch without a pull request. You can do that locally on your machine. Here are resources ([1](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge), [2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)). Merging branches without a pull requests has many valid scenarios (but mostly when you are working alone)

Comment: one more question when I do `git branch -a`, two branches appear `master` and `remotes/origin/master` branch. There is no `main`. Then how could I delete that main branch? I changed the default branch to master.

Comment: On github, go to your branches (click the branches icon) and there you should see the two branches and there will be a `trash` icon for the `main` branch. If you can't get around doing that. Then you need to `fetch` your `main` branch and then delete it locally and remotely.

Comment: GitHub now also has a settings page which lets you configure the default branch back to `master` like everyone in the universe is accustomed to having it. This way you you don’t have to suffer with conflicts between convention in your git CLI-tools and GitHub. 

https://github.com/settings/repositories