# Why I can't use git pull from master branch of github resprority?

Tags: git, github

Summary:

I have created a repository on GitHub, then I push my code to the repository `git push --set-upstream http://XXXXXXXXX  master`, it works!
Here is the master branch:

[image]

When I use another laptop pull it into local, `git clone http://XXXXXXX` it works, but the only main branch, not master branch, I don't know why.

[Here is the main branch,  actually I pull this branch to local:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R732K.png)

[Here is what I pull in local, no error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NekBW.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318908/6577998)?

Comment: Can you add what specific errors you are receiving?

Comment: During push you are creating branch a named "master" on the remote . Its not the actual MASTER. "main" is now the new name for master branch as per GitHub's initiative.

Comment: thanks, guys, I use git fetch, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just need to check out the branch you want to be on.

```sh
git fetch
git checkout master
git pull
```

Comment: @kitty If it works, then you may "Accept" this answer.

Comment: You indeed need to fetch first if the master branch is created on the remote after you cloned. I have updated my answer.